# Calculate Time difference between 2 given timestamps only considering day time of the day in Android?

Tags: android, timestamp

I've to 2 different epoch timestamp A and B. For each day i have different sunrise and sunset times. 
Suppose for day 1, which is timestamp A day sunrise time is 6.00 am and sun set time as 6.30 pm and for day2, sunrise time is 6.05 am and sunset time is 6.25pm, etc., below is the format i have,

```
val sunRise = mapOf<Int,String>(1 to "6.00", 2 to "6.05",3 to "6.01", 4 to "6.06")
val sunSet = mapOf<Int,String>(1 to "18.30", 2 to "18.25",3 to "18.20", 4 to "18.23")
val startTime = 1579919400000
val endTime = 1580203800000
```

Now how to calculate time taken between these to timestamps which are only between sunRise and sunSet in Android

Answer (score 0):

Try Below method will calculate difference between two times.

```
System.out.println("==result==: " + stringForTime(endTime - startTime));
public String stringForTime(long timeMs) {
        long totalSeconds = timeMs / 1000;

        long seconds = totalSeconds % 60;
        long minutes = (totalSeconds / 60) % 60;
        long hours = totalSeconds / 3600;

        Formatter mFormatter = new Formatter();

        if (hours > 0) {
            return mFormatter.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds).toString();
        } else {
            return mFormatter.format("%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds).toString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This just gives time difference between 2 timestamps, but what is wanted is the time taken between given timePeriod for each day. Can you go through my question once?